# Having Apache httpd listen on port 80, but not started as root?

Tags: linux, apache

I would like to have my Apache httpd launch as non-route user (httpd) and still listen on port 80/443. This server will be running on a Linux host.

Given that the first 1024 ports are reserved, how would I go about having a reserved port handled by a non-root daemon? Alternatively, can I run my apache on a non-reserved port and have the port's traffic redirect locally to that other port?

Comment: You cannot. To access those ports you need to be root

Comment: Can I have port 80's traffic redirected to another local port?

Comment: On linux (which means it's not portable to other unices) there's a capability to allow a non-root user to bind to a port in that range.  But apache has an option to run as a non privilege user, it switches ids after reserving that port and once done that, reverting to the root uid is not possible.  Check that option.  Sorry but, as this comment is not complete, I have not written it as an answer.

Comment: Being Linux specific is fine, since this is my target environment. I am happy with the iptables approach below. My main thing is isolating any daemon binaries to their own 'application' accounts. It may seem slightly paranoid, but I am in an environment where anything public facing should ideally be kept out of the root account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iptables for port redirecting:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: Use iptables-save for persistent saving this rule.

Comment: Just tried that and while my server is listening on the alternative port, the rules doesn't seem to work. I test using ```telnet localhost 80```, which gives me the error ```telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused```. Note ```telnet localhost 8080``` works.

Comment: check from another machine, or add one more rule:
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
And show me "iptables -L -n", maybe need  allow connection to 80 and 8080 ports.

Comment: This is working now (also needed to install iptables-persistent), though I see I'll need to do the same thing for ip6tables, though the version I have on Raspbian complains: ```ip6tables v1.4.14: unknown option "--to-port"```